# .Condarc file not working with Anaconda?

Tags: python, proxy, yaml, anaconda, conda

So I have the following `.condarc` file saved in my home directory:

```
proxy_servers: 
    http: proxyurl1 
    https: proxyurl2
```

However, when I try to use this, I get this error:

> Load error:  on line 1, column 0. Invalid YAML.

But what do I have wrong here? I built it based off of [this](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1757) example, and I can't see that I did anything very different. And it's saved as `.condarc` ?

[image]

What could be the error here?

Comment: Did you use a TAB before `http` instead of spaces (assuming line count starts at 0)?

Comment: @Anthon It was the tabs, thank you!